# Jquery Plugin Constructing ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how I would do this, basically when choosing the object for jquery to combine.

If you look at the example below I am trying to combine #toggle-btn- to say #toggle-btn-example for the object.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
    $.fn.togglebutton = function () {

        var myId = this;
        var toggleBtn = '#toggle-btn-'+ myId;
        var toggleInfo = '#toggle-info-'+ myId;

        $(toggleBtn).click(function(tb){
            tb.stopPropagation();
            $(toggleInfo).fadeIn(200);
            $(toggleBtn).hide();
        });

        $(toggleInfo).click(function(tb){
            tb.stopPropagation();
        });

        $(document).click(function(){

            $(toggleInfo).hide();
            $(toggleBtn).show();

        });

    };

    $('example').togglebutton();
```

My console throws this out:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #toggle-btn-[object Object]

Comment: please post your relevant html..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is a reference to the jQuery object!

Try:

```
var toggleBtn = '#toggle-btn-'+ this.attr("id");
```

Comment: `this` is actually a jQuery object.  `$.fn` is an alias for `jQuery.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that `this` is the id. This is incorrect.

Replace

```
var myId = this;
```

with

```
var myId = $(this).attr("id");
```

Comment: `this` is already a jQuery object.  `$.fn` is an alias for `jQuery.prototype`.  Just do `this.attr('id')`.